# Monitoring a server with top, ps, watch and timeout

Tags: bash

I would like for an hour, every 5s to dump the content of top and ps to log files. 
From the command line the following line works:

```
timeout 1h watch -n 5 'TMS=`date +%s`;top -bn1>>top-$TMS.log;ps aux>>ps-$TMS.log;'
```

But placed in a file (if I call: `./monitor-server.sh`), the logs are not created.

The `timeout` command does not seem to work inside the script. If I do the same call with the script (without timeout) like:

```
watch -n 5 'TMS=`date +%s`;top -bn1>>top-$TMS.log;ps aux>>ps-$TMS.log;'
```

that works...

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to run it in background to avoid having dependency from your parent process (shell). Try:

```
nohup timeout 1h watch -n 5 'TMS=`date +%s`;top -bn1>>top-$TMS.log;ps aux>>ps-$TMS.log;' &
```

Comment: Thanks modified the script and it works by calling the script. But I can't seem to plan a job like:" at -f ./monitor-server.sh now "?

Comment: @Alain it should be the last (parent) process under `ps auxf`

Comment: I am running the line (mentionned above) in a script called by at -f monitor-server.sh . I don't see the process with ps auxf. ?

Comment: I tried taking out nohup and replaced & with 2>error.log ? I get "Error opening terminal: unknown". Echoed $TERM = xterm.

Comment: nohup will log errors to nohup.log in your current directory, try locating the script by $$ (process pid)

Comment: I finally resolved my problem with at, to the script I added: export TERM=linux and it works if I do at -f monitor-server.sh now. Thanks for your help.